# Как добавить индикатор macd к графику?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import mplfinance as mpf
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf


#Сбор данных
btc = yf.Ticker("ETH-USD").history(period = "1mo", interval = "60m")

mpf.plot(btc,
         type = "renko",
         style = "binance")
```

В этом коде создается простой renko график, как к нему добавить индикатор macd, чтобы он находился ниже графика

Comment: вам для начала нужно получить данные для macd-инлдикатора. Например, с помощью pandas-ta или TA-Lib. а дальше уже - дело техники.